# Print out only the last 30 days with mysql or bash

Tags: mysql, bash

I am no expert in this but I spent some time to get this command print

```
echo "SELECT datetime(last_visit_date/1000000,'unixepoch'),
url FROM moz_places WHERE last_visit_date NOT NULL AND url NOT NULL 
ORDER BY last_visit_date DESC;"  | sqlite3 places.sqlite >> SOMEFILE
```

OUTPUT:

```
2012-08-10 11:26:00|http://support.mozilla.org/questions/835204
2012-08-10 11:25:46|http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/867052
2012-08-09 23:58:43|http://joecristianospizza.com/locations.htm
2012-08-09 23:56:14|http://joecristianospizza.com/
```

(note I can also print in unixtimestamp)

I Can't figure out how to make this only print 30 days ... 
Tried:

```
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY). etc. no luck!
```

Help! 
I could also do it with bash, these lists will be in a temp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
WHERE datetime(last_visit_date/1000000,'unixepoch') >= 
                      DATETIME('now', '-30 DAY')
```

Comment: if you use `DATE_SUB` you should use `INTERVAL +30 DAY`, correct?

Comment: Tried to a simpler version :  echo "SELECT * FROM moz_places WHERE last_visit_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);" | sqlite3 places.sqlite 
Error: near line 1: near "30": syntax error

Comment: I tried something like it and it didn't work before, I created a work around... will try again later today